# Word for emergent image

Tags: word-choice

What is this called?

[image: An image of a face made up of images of baseball players. There are 462 (22 by 21) smaller images making up the larger image.]

I know it's a collage, but is there more specific term for a collection of a pictures arranged in a way that creates the illusion of a "big picture" from amongst them?

Bonus: What's a better word than "illusion" to describe that "big picture"?

Comment: Also see [What is the style of art in which small numbers are used to paint pictures called?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/125644),

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A photographic mosaic or photomosaic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_mosaic

Comment: +1 Photomosaic is exactly what I asked for, so I've accepted. It's a little bit on-the-nose for my use-case though - I wonder if there are any more general terms for this sort of phenomenon. A photomosaic is a form or type of _____ ?

Comment: @drewmore: It is a type of collage which you already mentioned in your question. But as it is usually computer-created, it is a montage also.

Comment: A photomosaic is a type of mosaic, oddly enough. :)